How to Adjust the Order of Sublist Fields in NetSuite Kit/Item Records Using SuiteScript?
I have customized some sublist fields in the Kit/Item records of NetSuite using SuiteScript. However, when I attempted to adjust the display order of these fields, I found that the official modules provided by NetSuite don't seem to include code for adjusting the order of sublist fields. I'm not sure if I missed some relevant documentation. Is there a way to edit the display order of sublist fields using SuiteScript in NetSuite?

Do it on the Sublist Fields subtab when customizing the entry form. Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1515597095.html
